# when cpu temp get higher than 70 then kill process

Tags: bash

hi im trying to make a script that help me control the temp of my cpu when i create hash files
but it keep sayaing missing when it get to le process stoping here is my script

```
M=70
while
R1=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`
R2=$(($R1 / 1000))
R3=`top -bn 1 | awk 'NR>7{s+=$9} END {print s}'`
echo  "$Bl Cpu Temp $R2°C $R3$% Usage"
do
sleep 2
if [$R2 -ge $M]; then
kill -STOP 
fi
done
```

when i run the script it give me

> Cpu Temp 62°C @ 100 % Usage
>
> cpu.sh: 13: cpu.sh: [62: not found

Comment: With bash you can do `if (( R2 >= M )); then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
 if [$R2 -ge $M]; then
```

with

```
 if [ "$R2" -ge "$M" ]; then
```

spaces are significant, because `[` is really [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) (often, a [built-in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) variant inside your shell). Double-quotes are useful for the cases like `$R2` being empty...

Read [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)...

Comment: thanks it work now ,how can i make it resume the process

Comment: `kill -CONT <pid>`... It would need to run from a different process though, since the stopped process is unable to run it...